# tensor flow eval() function in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, dictionary, eval

My question relates to this code block:

Code is:

```
  import tensorflow as tf

    W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", shape=[4,4,3,8], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 0))
    W2 = tf.get_variable("W2", shape=[2,2,8,16], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 0))


    parameters = {"W1": W1,
                  "W2": W2}

    print("W1[1,1,1] = \n" + str(parameters["W1"].eval()[1,1,1]))
    print("W2[1,1,1] = \n" + str(parameters["W2"].eval()[1,1,1]))
```

How should we interpret the `eval()` and and the dimensions `[1, 1, 1]`. What does `eval()` return?

```
parameters["W1"].eval()[1,1,1]
```

The `print` statement containing the `eval()` is:

```
print("W1[1,1,1] = \n" + str(parameters["W1"].eval()[1,1,1]))
```

Comment: use `print( parameters["W1"] )` and `print( parameters["W1"].eval() )` to see what `eval()` returns. OR find`eval()` in `tensorflow` documentation. This way you could answer few hours ago without asking on Stackoverflow.

Comment: `print( parameters["W1"] )` as expected gives is `<tf.Variable 'W1:0' shape=(4, 4, 3, 8) dtype=float32_ref>`. But - `print( parameters["W1"].eval() )` returns in this error (even though W1 in initialized: `FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value W1   [[Node: _retval_W1_0_0 = _Retval[T=DT_FLOAT, index=0, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](W1)]]`

Comment: you could read doc for [eval](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#eval) - `Calling this method will execute all preceding operations that produce the inputs needed for the operation that produces this tensor.` As I know `tensorflow` is lazy running - it doesn't process operations at once but you have to use `eval()` to do it.